# Does javascript make a copy of a variable when it is passed to a function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Hi I have a google maps polygons array named `regionPolygons`. Now I want each time I click a polygon, my map will set its center at that of the polygon.
Here is how I implement it.

```
for (i = 0; i < regionPolygons.length; i++) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(regionPolygons[i], 'click', function () {                
    // do the stuff, things seem ok here
  }
}
```

Now whichever polygons I click, I am taken to the center of the last polygon. 
How can I let Google maps now which polygon is clicked?
Thank you

**Edit**: My question a duplicate. It seems that copying the same code to the new function work. It seems that Javascript create new copy of the variable when it  is passed from the main program to a sub program. Could any one help me explain about it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be sensible for Google to make the clicked polygon available within the event handler as `this` or as `event.target` but the API documentation gives no clues that that's actually done. By all means try.

If neither of those suggestions works, then you can exploit a closure to keep a copy of `i`, as follows :

```
for(var i=0; i<regionPolygons.length; i++) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(regionPolygons[i], 'click', (function(i) {
        return function() {
            var polygon = regionPolygons[i];
            //do stuff here with `polygon`
        };
    })(i));
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the same technique to keep a reference to the polygon object itself :

```
for(var i=0; i<regionPolygons.length; i++) {
    var p = regionPolygons[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(p, 'click', (function(polygon) {
        return function() {
            //do stuff here with `polygon`
        };
    })(p));
}
```

The nett effect is the same; inside the event handler, you end up with a reference to the clicked polygon.

Comment: It seems that your methods did not work for my code. Nevertheless, I really appreciate your help :). Thank you.

Comment: Total success still depends on what you write to replace the placeholder "do stuff here with `polygon".

Comment: The same thing works if I copy the `do stuff here` to a new function. I would try your solution again though